# How can I tell SuperCSV to map empty `String` attributes when using `CsvDozerBeanWriter`?

Tags: java, csv, dozer, supercsv

I'm using `CsvDozerBeanWriter` to write a bean instance to a CSV file. Following the [example](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_dozer.html) code I've used `CsvDozerBeanWriter#configureBeanMapping(...)` before writing the bean to CSV. Everything works well except when the bean has `String` attributes that are empty (rather than `null`). I find that such attributes are not copied from the bean to the  intermediate `CsvDozerBeanData` instance before writing. This causes an exception as the number of columns then don't match the number of cell processors.

Digging in I found that `configureBeanMapping(...)` performs the equivalent of setting Dozer's `map-empty-string` to `False`. All *empty* strings are therefore not mapped (`null` strings still get mapped).

How do I overcome this? Is providing my own `DozerBeanMapper` (as the [documentation](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/dozer.html) says) the best way to go?

### Update:

Here are the details of the exception I got:

```
 org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvException: The number of columns to be processed (7) must match the number of CellProcessors (12): check that the number of CellProcessors you have defined matches the expected number of columns being read/written
context={lineNo=2, rowNo=2, columnNo=1, rowSource=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]}
org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvException: The number of columns to be processed (7) must match the number of CellProcessors (12): check that the number of CellProcessors you have defined matches the expected number of columns being read/written
context={lineNo=2, rowNo=2, columnNo=1, rowSource=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]}
    at org.supercsv.util.Util.executeCellProcessors(Util.java:78)
    at org.supercsv.io.dozer.CsvDozerBeanWriter.write(CsvDozerBeanWriter.java:133)
```

The bean has `String` attributes `a` through `l`. Attributes `h` through `l` are empty strings.

### Update 2:

Here is a [test case](https://gist.github.com/4379763).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `map-empty-string` is disabled, then the value passed to the cell processors should be `null` (i.e. you'd most likely get an error from the processor for that column saying the value shouldn't be null - not an exception about there being the wrong number of processors). If you could post the exception details to clarify this that would be great :)

After running some tests with `CsvDozerBeanWriter`, it looks like the Dozer mapping API was fixed in Dozer 5.4.0 (see [this](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/commit/aaf62b8c4d025dd764d8b27b25289eb07f5e38ac) commit).

- In Dozer 5.3.2 `""` is mapped to `null`
- In Dozer 5.4.0 `""` is mapped to `""`

Unfortunately there's no detailed release notes for Dozer 5.4.0 (and no issue created on GitHub - they're still in the process of being migrated from SourceForge) to make this easier to find out.

If you can upgrade to Dozer 5.4.0, then that should fix your problem. I'm planning on upgrading Super CSV to Dozer 5.4.0 in the next release (early next year), but there's nothing stopping you from overriding the version inherited from Super CSV right now.

If you're stuck on Dozer 5.3.2 for some reason, then I'd suggest you either:

- write your own Writer that extends `CsvDozerBeanWriter` (but override the `configureBeanMapping()` method to provide a `MappingBuilder` that has `map-empty-string` enabled)
- use `CsvBeanWriter` (if you're not using indexed/deep mapping)

FYI I encountered another bug with the mapping API in 5.3.2 that meant I had to enable `map-null` at the class level instead of the mapping level when writing `CsvDozerBeanWriter`- this has also been fixed in 5.4.0 (though Super CSV will function correctly with either version of Dozer).

Comment: Thanks. I've added relevant parts of the exception stack trace to my question.

Comment: Great, can you also post the code calling `configureBeanMapping()`? There should be 12 elements in the array you're passing in...

Comment: Give me a few minutes. Will post a simplified test case. Thanks again.

Comment: Please have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/4379763  There is a bean `Person` and a test class `DozerBugTest`. I was able to reproduce the error using Dozer 5.3.2 and SuperCSV 2.0.1. For what it is worth I'm using Java 1.6.

Comment: Great, yes now I understand. Because they're all empty from `h` onwards, Dozer doesn't add any elements to the list because of the incorrect `map-empty-string` value. If the last column wasn't empty it would actually work! Let me know if my solution works.

Comment: The simplified test case passed when I used Dozer 5.4.0. I'll do the same for my original code and see if it does the trick.

Comment: And it looks like Dozer 5.4.0 indeed did the trick :) Thanks!